# Opinions on updating EVF question

Tags: discussion, editing

[Disadvantages of electronic viewfinders?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34193/disadvantages-of-electronic-viewfinders) is a pretty useful basic question, although the answer could use some modernization. However, the question (and answer) refers to Sony SLT, which is

1. a special case, and
2. no longer made.

Plus, there's [What are the disadvantages of SLT-cameras and are they THAT bad?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/53883/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-slt-cameras-and-are-they-that-bad), specifically on that.

I'd like a general EVF question relevant to today's cameras and without the pellicle mirror complication. What do you think about either:

A. Editing references to the SLT cameras out of 34193, or

B. Editing 34193 to specifically refer to the SLT and creating a new question on EVF vs optical viewfinder for 2019?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say leave both the old ones as they are and just ask an updated question that can more properly couch the question to address the current differences between EVFs. With questions that include a lot of technical specifications, we're always going to be shooting at a moving target. That doesn't mean we should ignore valid questions about how different camera models/camera makers might approach technical challenges differently.

Comment: [okay done](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/105179/1943). I did copy the first line of the existing question which refers to SLTs into its title to reduce future confusion.

Comment: Oh. I thought we were talking about comparing different EVFs to each other. Either way, my opinion above is the same.

Answer (score 0):

SLTs are still being sold as current, for example the a68 and a99Mk2. Also, as long as a certain class of equipment is widely available on the used market, answers relating to it are perfectly useful for people that love shopping in the past.